# Text Index Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Im a beginner in MongoDB2.6. I'm exploring "Text" indexing in Mongodb.

My Collection has below documents.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54961bfa913a9f096e9390a3"), "Comments" : "David went to Park today" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54961e5b913a9f096e9390a7"), "Comments" : "David went to Park today", "Toldby" : "How are You" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54961be4913a9f096e9390a1"), "Comments" : "Park in Irvine are beautiful"}
```

I have created an "Text" Index on Comments Column.
`db.textcollection.find({$text:{$search:"Park"}})`  --> This Command returns all three documents

But when i try to replace "Park" with "in" i get no output, should it return the last document for me? . Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common words of the text index's configured language (english, by default) are known as "stop words" and are excluded from the index.  Examples from your strings are words like "to", "in", and "are". As such, you won't get any results if you search on those words.

If you actually need those words included, then you can set the text index's [language](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/) to `"none"` which disables all the smarts of stop words and word stemming.